# Calculating preparation dates and adjusting for weekends

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, weekday

I am working on a Google Sheets that calculates prep time needed for my events.

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy2lu.png)

My events have a 'Ship Date' that is used in calculating my 'Prep Start' and 'Prep End' days. I am currently using array formula to pull my 'Ship Date' and then add the necessary 'Prep Days' needed.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(E2:E-N2:N)
```

I am trying to find a way to add additional prep time if the 'Prep Date' falls on a weekend.

Is there a way that I can use the weekday function in my existing array formula so that if the 'Prep Start' falls on a Saturday/Sunday additional days are added?

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statement in arrayformula

eg

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A-B1:B+if(WEEKDAY(A1:A;2)>5;8-weekday(A1:A;2);0))
```

By using type 2 in weekday, Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7, this allows for compensating the weekend.